# Convert two dictionaries to a dictionary of dictionaries containing all combinations

Tags: python, dictionary

**Problem**

I have two dictionaries: a and b

```
a={'e':[1,2]}
b={'d':[11,22]}
```

How can I convert them to a dictionary of dictioneries that contains all possible combinations of the lists `[1,2]` and `[11,22]`. The expected result should be:

```
 dic={1:{'e':1,'d':11},
      2:{'e':2,'d':22},
      3:{'e':1,'d':11},
      4:{'e':2,'d':22}}
```

**My attemt:**

I can easily get the combinations of two lists or any set of lists using `itertools` like so:

```
l=list(itertools.product([1,2],[11,22]))
```

But I don't know how to proceed from here. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you mean:


dic={1:{'e':1,'d':11},
      2:{'e':1,'d':22},
      3:{'e':2,'d':11},
      4:{'e':2,'d':22}}


by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it. Just have to create dictionaries by mapping keys to the tuples in `l`.

```
keys = list(a.keys()) + list(b.keys())
dic = {k: dict(zip(keys, tpl)) for k, tpl in enumerate(l), 1)}
```

Here's a bit more generalized approach:

(i) First combine the dictionaries:

```
combined = {**a, **b}
```

(ii) Find the Cartesian product the list items in `combined.values()`.

(iii) Iterate over outcome from (ii) and create dictionaries with each tuple and the keys in `combined.keys()`:

```
dic = {k: dict(zip(combined.keys(), tpl)) for k, tpl in enumerate(itertools.product(*combined.values()), 1)}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'e': 1, 'd': 11}, 2: {'e': 1, 'd': 22}, 3: {'e': 2, 'd': 11}, 4: {'e': 2, 'd': 22}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `l` as you calculated it you can use dict comprehension and achieve the required output -

```
{idx+1 : {'e': item[0], 'd': item[1]} for idx, item in enumerate(l)}
```

(BTW there is no need to convert the `itertools.product` result to list)